# Ajax post method returns undefined in .net mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, post

I have this ajax post method in my code that returns undefined. I think its because I have not passed in any data, any help will be appreciated.

I have tried passing the url string using the @Url.Action Helper and passing data in as a parameter in the success parameter in the ajax method.

//jquery ajax post method

```
function SaveEvent(data) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("Bookings/SaveBooking")',
                    data: data,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.status) {
                            //Refresh the calender
                            FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
                            $('#myModalSave').modal('hide');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        alert('Failed' + error.val );
                    }
                })
            }
```

//controller action

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SaveBooking(Booking b)
    {
        var status = false;
        using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            if (b.ID > 0) 
            {
                //update the event
                var v = db.Bookings.Where(a => a.ID == a.ID);
                if (v != null)
                {
                    v.SingleOrDefault().Subject = b.Subject;
                    v.SingleOrDefault().StartDate = b.StartDate;
                    v.SingleOrDefault().EndDate = b.EndDate;
                    v.SingleOrDefault().Description = b.Description;
                    v.SingleOrDefault().IsFullDay = b.IsFullDay;
                    v.SingleOrDefault().ThemeColor = b.ThemeColor;
                }
                else
                {
                    db.Bookings.Add(b);
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
                status = true;
            }
        }
        return new JsonResult { Data = new { status } };
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the ajax call, you should collect the data in object like,

```
  var requestData= {
    ModelField1: 'pass the value here',
     ModelField2: 'pass the value here')
  };
```

Please note, I have only added two fields but as per your class declaration, you can include all your fields.

it should be like :

```
  function SaveEvent(data) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action(Bookings,SaveBooking)', 
                data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.status) {
                        //Refresh the calender
                        FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
                        $('#myModalSave').modal('hide');
                    }
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert('Failed' + error.val );
                }
            })
        }
```

Comment: can you show me the correct syntax in an example please

Comment: I have posted the the code for ajax call as well as the request data, you can use above code to perform the operation.

Comment: I made the changes as you suggested but I still have the same issue. I get a 404 error

Comment: please make sure you have the correct controller and action method name in the ajax call.

Comment: I have made sure that the controller and action method name are correct, Could there be a problem in the way I call the data from the form?

Comment: when you make the ajax call, please look at the console window in the browser to see how the request is being proceeded. Is there any errors in browser console window?

Comment: I logged the object I'm getting empty strings back from the object parameters no matter which jquery function I use (.val,.html,.text)

Comment: You can put the debugger in the jquery method and try to inspect it through browser to see, whether the method is calling or not. You can check the network tab to see any XHR requests are being made or not. This will give you an idea as whether the problem is at your front end or at the back end.

Comment: The problem should be in the front end because I can't even log the properties of the newly revised requestData object.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cYG6vi, I have made a demo for you. Please review it at once.

Comment: i forgot to use the "begin form" helper method so far, I am still working on a few back end errors. Thanks for helping me get the front end working.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `contentType:'Application/json',` to your ajax and simply have:

`return Json(status);`

In your controller instead of JsonResult. As well as this, You will need to pass the data in the ajax code as a stringified Json such as:

`data:JSON.stringify(data),`

Also, is there nay reason in particular why it's a `JsonResult` method?